amsbook imakeindex indexprologue doesn't appear
I have an amsbook manuscript with two indexes and would like to add a prologue to one of these using the indexprologue command of the imakeindex package.  However, as in the following MWE the prologue comment doesn't appear.  This is  pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023)
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage[original]{imakeidx}
\makeindex[name=subjects,title=Subject Index]
\makeindex[name=names,title=Names Index]

\begin{document}
The research program laid out by \index[names]{Robbins, H.}
\index[subjects]{Incidental Parameters}


\printindex[subjects]
\indexprologue{\small ``These are the men who pretend to understand a book by scouting 
through the index, as if a traveller should go about to describe a palace, 
when he had seen nothing but the privy.'' [Jonathan Swift (1704)]}
\printindex[names]
\end{document}


Welcome to TeX.SX!

From the package documentation:

In particular, \indexprologue cannot have effect. Remove the option.
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[name=subjects,title=Subject Index]
\makeindex[name=names,title=Names Index]

\begin{document}
The research program laid out by \index[names]{Robbins, H.}
\index[subjects]{Incidental Parameters}


\printindex[subjects]
\indexprologue{\small ``These are the men who pretend to understand a book by scouting
through the index, as if a traveller should go about to describe a palace,
when he had seen nothing but the privy.'' [Jonathan Swift (1704)]}
\printindex[names]
\end{document}


